# Call an action in ASP.NET MVC 2 with MS Ajax without jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

How can I call an action in ASP.NET MVC 2 with MS Ajax when I don`t want to use jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you want to use jquery?  You can always role your own with XMLHttpRequest http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/ but I think jQuery makes it so much easier.